# I need to convert org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]] to Array[Byte] in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scala-collections

I am trying to parse json file into spark streaming through kafka.

I wrote a function which requires `Array[Byte]`.

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd=>
    parseAVROToString(rdd)
)

ssc.start
```

To use `parseAVROToString` I need `Array[Byte]`.
I am getting the following error message :

```
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]] required: Array[Byte] parseAVROToString(rdd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreach(record = > parseAVROToString(record))
})
```

But `foreachRDD` is an output operation which used to to save underline rdds to external files or databases. I think `stream.transform` might be useful in your case.

Comment: I am able to pass this function, however I am unable to print the string that I'm getting through parseAVROToString function as it's coming inside the stream, Is there any way?

Comment: try this `stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      rdd.foreach(record => {
        println(parseAVROToString(record))
      })
    })` **Note that this will print records in slave nodes console**

Comment: I think you might be seeing driver console! check worker node logs. or if you are debugging try this code `.transform(rdd => {
      val parsedRDD = rdd.map(record => {
        parseAVROToString(record)
      })
      parsedRDD
    }).print()` This will print 10 sample records on driver console.

Comment: It doesn't work, Is there no way to check whether my parse function is actually working or not.........thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: What did you get? any error? people often uses transform and print for debugging purposes! Ok, lets put in this way, what are you returning in parseAVROToString? Are you returning string? then should be printed on console!

Comment: ERROR: value parsedRDD is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
I'm returning string ..

Comment: I'm sure `parseAVROToString` is not returning `string` that's why you were not getting parsedRDD as `RDD[String]`. Can you double check parse function return type!

Comment: I am using this exact code -
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/33275/receiving-avro-messages-through-kafka-in-a-spark-s.html#comment-45177
it does not show my dataframe saved anywhere in any format..

Comment: Are you using Avro or plain JSON?

Comment: @avr Could you please look into this!!

Comment: @AayushRampal Do you mind to share complete code(hope it is just test code)!

Comment: @avr, thanks buddy, solved that issue, problem was I was using zepplin, when i ran it on intellij it worked fine, thanks for your help!!